# How Do I See My Assignments in Trello?

Tags: trello

Across several boards, several lists, several cards, there are tasks "assigned" to me.  Is there an easy way to see them all in one place?

Answer (score 3):

You can't see a master list of everything assigned to you, but you can easily see what's assigned to you on a given board.  While you're hovering your mouse over anything except a card, smack <kbd>Q</kbd>, and everything that isn't assigned to you will disappear.  To get everything back, just smack <kbd>Q</kbd> again.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a single place to do that.

I've [created a card for that feature](https://trello.com/card/board/way-to-see-all-cards-on-all-boards-that-are-assigned-to-me/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e7769045752db7c7e44bcc2), feel free to vote that up or add comments.

Comment: You don't need to make all your answers community wiki unless you're expecting a group effort to fill in the holes

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise: Okay ... I felt bad collecting rep for not having implemented a feature ;)

Comment: @DanielLeCheminant You appear to have forgotten one of your own features, if it makes you feel better for getting karma for not having implemented the feature.

Comment: @Benjamin: The question asked "Across Several Boards", and that's the feature that we don't have :D  [Q] mode is awesome though...

Answer (score 1):

This is now available here and very useful

https://trello.com/my/cards